# Scare away giant water bugs

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In Animal Crossing New Horizons, there's a money making strategy on mystery islands where you remove the things that allow bug spawns like trees and flowers to increase the spawn chance of tarantulas.

Then you just run around scaring away any other bugs that spawn to allow for tarantulas to spawn.

Now that it's April, a bug called Giant Water Bug can spawn. And it's everywhere. My map is spawning nothing but those right now, and I can't figure out how to scare them away. It seems like I have to just catch them, but this takes too long and burns through nets.

Is there a better way to deal with these bugs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're lucky and land on Bamboo Island, islands with ponds and water bugs seem like a lost cause to me.
Although time consuming, do the typical farming setup: remove all trees, flowers, and rocks. Then dig up all the grass - this prevents multiple Mole Crickets - except for a square like the on in the picture below. And one line, for running to the rocks, on the back row. Bugs won't spawn in small areas like this.
Then run to rocks, scare Wharf Roaches, return to your square, where there will either be Tiger Beetles or Tarantulas, repeat, and get bells!
Tried for an hour without digging, only got about five. 30 minutes with digging, and I had a full inventory, and had to drop tools.

[image: Bamboo island for tarantula farming with mole crickets]

Comment: I tried to do this as well, but it is too mind-numbing to dig all the area... GJ confirming this is profitable!!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get rid of giant water bugs is by catching them with a net and releasing them.

They don't despawn when you run near the water's edge, use your vaulting pole or ladder nearby, or by using a fishing rod on top of them. Unfortunately, I've had to bring two nets at least to every island to account for them. They sell for a fourth of the tarantula pricing, clocking in at 2,000 bells compared to 8,000 bells, excluding Flick. He's at my island right now as I'm grinding, so we are in the exact same boat, my man. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

After a long hunt I think I may have figured out at least how to slow the spawning of giant water bugs. I was on an island with a pond and a river, each spawning these devils.

What I think slowed the spawn of them was I kept a constant eye on the water. It may have caused them only to spawn when they were out of view when I went to scare off other bugs and wharf roaches.

I also have a whole new appreciation for the wharf roach.